# copy SSRS 2008 report descriptions to another machine?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm working on syncing up a backup box with a production server and I have tons of reports which have descriptions with them that need to copy over.

I've found that the description data is in the reportingservices database in the catalog table. However none of the guids match up so I can't just drop this info into the other database and overwrite the .

Has anyone had to do this before and is there a shortcut to doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep, I used this tool: http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62

Comment: I just completed doing 100 something update statements by hand, lol. Too bad I didn't check my responses sooner. But, now I have a script. I'll try the tool next time the need arises. Thanks.